# React-Native: Using different config.json for dev and prod

Tags: react-native

I have React-Native project which I'm testing on my "**staging**" server. Now its time to release it on "**production**" server.

I'm using config.json file which consists with server info such as api keys, api address, and so on.

What I want is to use different config.json for "production" and "staging". And when I use production config.json, there would be no traces of staging config.json in my bundle.

```
src
- config
-- config.js
-- production-server.json
-- staging-server.json
```

maybe something like: yarn build-staging, yarn build-production

Comment: Are you sure you have problems with react-native? `react-native` is about mobile development! Not about servers ;-)

Comment: Yeah. Mobile app connects to api server right? And for staging and production this servers are different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried react-native-config? It allows to set up different configuration files for different environments. For more details, you can go through this article [Link](https://medium.com/differential/managing-configuration-in-react-native-cd2dfb5e6f7b)